# Redisplaying plots in Matplotlib in conjunction with PyQt

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt4

I have a program written using PyQt and Matplotlib which I am using to display stellar spectra.

The program has a dialog box which I can use to select the required spectra and adjust the X/Y scales and other things.

When changes are made in the dialog box, I have the code do (with matplotlib.pylab imported s plt)

```
plt.clf()
(replot the newly-selected spectra)
plt.show()
```

This works fine with older versions of Matplotlib (1.0.0)

However with later versions of Matplotlib (I'm trying 1.3.1), I get strange results. I'm OK the first time round but each subsequent attempt fails to update the plot. I also get lots of messages:

```
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
```

each time the program tries to invoke the above code and the plot is not updated.

If I change the last part of my code to say

```
plt.show(False)
```

That makes the messages go away but the plot is still not updated.

The only way I can make the plot get updated is to change the

```
plt.clf()
```

to

```
plt.close()
```

but that looks horrible as the display window closes and reopens every time I select a different spectrum.

Is there a better way of doing all this?

I'd rather use the new version of Matplotlib if I can as I also need to use the newer versions of Scipy which has routines in I am using which aren't in the older versions. At the University I'm working it's either "all old" or "all new" as far as versions of the software are concerned.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Thank you! I really needed that interactive(True) statement :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I do:

```
matplotlib.interactive(True)
```

and don't bother with any parameters to show() and it does what I want.